# What are plotly.express, plotly.io, and plotly.go and when do we use them?

Tags: python, plotly

What are plotly.express, plotly.io, and plotly.go and when do we use them? I keep running into them in the [Plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/), but I can't really figure out what the differences are. My guess is that plotly.express is the most general-use part of the plotly API and plotly.go is used more commonly when you want to publish a graph as HTML or in some other format, but I suspect that this crude impression is incorrect. Any thoughts, comments, or general advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Plotly Express is higher level convenient to use API.  It's built on top of graph objects.  Almost all times I see ppl getting tied up in knots using graph objects I encourage them to use express

Answer (score -1):

The graph objects are the basis of a plotly express library, plotly express requires only one line of code as opposed to a hundred with graph objects.  The plotly express library does not yet support 3D, parallel coordinates, faces, or animated figures.

Comment: this should have been a comment, but I don't have enough reputation. @santosh's answer isn't correct in regard to 3d and animation. every plotly express figure can be animated using 'animation_frame' parameter and there is 3d support vie scatter_3d.

Comment: Alright i'll get back to you with proper information.